# xml node value as variable for get-childitem (directory)

Tags: xml, variables, get-childitem

i want to read from a XML file paths and perform actions later on the files inside the paths.

xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<folders>
  <folder>
    d:\test
  </folder>
</folders> 



[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path Desktop\test.xml

foreach( $directory in $XmlDocument.folders.folder)
{
$Files = get-childitem $directory
DoSomeAction
}
```

My problem is i cant get the $folder variable into the right object type or whatever...

Thanks much in advance

cheers

Comment: Sry iam new, the content of the xml file and the ps script code was intedended to be in different code blocks ;)

Comment: What if you use `$directory.Trim()`?  There might be whitespace around the directory name that is preserved.

Comment: @weigsi `$directory.InnerText.Trim()`?

Answer (score 0):

> What if you use $directory.Trim()? There might be whitespace around the directory name that is preserved. – Grisha Levit 7 hours ago